# Cumulant of sum of correlated random variables?

Tags: independence, correlation, cumulants

Let $X,Y$ be two random variables. We denote by $[X^k]$ and $[Y^k]$ the $k$'th order cumulants of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. I'm interested in computing the $k$'th order cumulant of $Z = X+Y$.

If $X,Y$ were independent, then a well-known property implies that $[Z^k] = [X^k] + [Y^k]$.

Now suppose $X,Y$ are *not* independent. Can we write an expression for the cumulants of $Z$, from the cumulants of $X$, $Y$, plus additional terms related to the dependence between $X$ and $Y$ (e.g., the cumulants of products $XY$?

Comment: You also asked this at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/460613/119261. Please avoid cross-posting in general.